# Expanding an argument of code added by \g@addto@macro

Tags: macros, expansion

I would like to have the following (it's a part of a large code block):

```
\def\C{foobar}
\def\A{}
\g@addto@macro\A{\B{\C}}
```

Now `\show\A` outputs `\B{\C}`

I would like to modify the 3rd line so that `\show\A` outputs `\B{foobar}`

I believe that some trick with `\expandafter` should help, but I'm not familiar with it. (Note: `expl3` would surely help here, but I'd like to avoid it.)

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\C{foobar}
\def\A{}
\g@addto@macro\A{\B{\C}}

\show\A

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are we allowed to use e-TeX? Do you want to fully expand `\C` or to expand it exactly once? Can we assume `\C` is fully-expandable inside an `\edef`?

Comment: @JosephWright e-TeX is fine, and `\C` is expandable. I should have specified it, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\def\C{\D}
\def\D{foobar}
\def\A{}
\edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\A{\noexpand\B{\C}}}
\next
\show\A

\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\A\expandafter{\expandafter\B\expandafter{\C}}
\show\A
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The variants are different: the `\edef` will expand fully, the `\expandafter` only one level.

Comment: We don't know the internal structure of `\C`. I was about to write more or less the same answer, but would favour using a `\toks` or `\unexpanded` in the `\edef` case for this reason.

Comment: And there is `\protected@edef` if LaTeX's `\protect` mechanisms should be supported.

Comment: The first variant works perfectly. I should have specified that `\C` should be fully expanded, which is how it works. Thanks a lot! (Damn, I have to remember that trick with `\noexpand`.)

Comment: @JosephWright: There are lots of possible variants but the first step is to understand and decide about the expansion level. So I did not try to suppress full expansion in the first case.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek If you do a single expansion level using a `\toks` or `\unexpanded` then `\protected@edef` should not be needed.

Comment: @JosephWright In case of a fully expand using `\edef`. It is not clear, which kind of expansion is needed and what is the kind of contents for `\C`.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, a LaTeX3 solution would look something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \C
\tl_set:Nn \C { foobar }
\tl_new:N \A
\tl_gput_right:Nx \A { \exp_not:N \B { \exp_not:V \C } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\A

\end{document}
```

(We are not told anything about `\B`, so I've assuming it might be expandable.) I have assumed `\C` is a variable, and have deliberately only expanded it to it's value: you could miss out the `\exp_not:V` and have x-type expansion.

Answer (score 2):

```
\def\C{foobar}
 \def\A{}     
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\A\expandafter{%
 \expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\B\expandafter{\C}}
```

or define

```
\def\C{foobar}     
\def\A{}     
\edef\X{\noexpand\B{\C}}
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\A\expandafter{\X}
```