# Expanding a parameter token argument to \g@addto@macro

Tags: macros, expansion

Consider the following example.

By default `\g@addto@macro` doesn't expand its arguments, which can have unexpected results when passing a macro as an argument, if the macro value is changed later.

To expand the macro argument, I used the workaround shown below. Does this approach have any disadvantages? Is there a better way to do this?

In this example code, `\append` doesn't expand its argument. `\newappend` does. They both append the argument `#1` (followed by a comma) to the macros `\slist` and `\newslist` respectively.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\def\slist{}
\def\newslist{}

\makeatletter
\def\append#1
{
 \g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}%
}
\def\newappend#1
{
  \def\tmpmacroval{#1}
  \edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{\tmpmacroval,}}%
  \next
}
\makeatother

\def\foo{fooval}

\begin{document}
\append{\foo}

\newappend{\foo}

\def\foo{someotherval}

\verb|\slist| is \slist

\verb|\newslist| is \newslist
\end{document}
```

ADDENDUM: I omitted the context of this question for simplicity, but 
the argument to `\append`/`\newappend` is basically a label. This is normally just a string of characters, but I started using a variant which is a single macro which expands to a string, with a string appended. E.g. `\theletternum:2019.09.30`, where `letternum` is a counter, defined by `\stepcounter{letternum}`. In this case, the argument needs to be expanded before being appended to `\slist`/`\newslist`. I don't currently think that the input will get more complicated than that, but of course it's hard to see the future.

Comment: Well you are fully expanding your `\tmpmacroval/\foo` command. This could explode if the command contains stuff that better shouldn't be passed through an \edef. Better use \protected@edef, or expand only once. And consider to use expl3 which has readymade commands for this.

Comment: expl3 has readymade commands for what?

Comment: To append content to commands and to expand them if wanted.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I see. Can you provide a relevant link? Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67372/3406 perhaps?

Comment: most latex commands will fail in an edef

Comment: why are you defining `\newappend` with a delimited argument?  Try  the exmple: `\newappend{a}\newappend{b} `, it will fail spectacularly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you elaborate on what you mean by a delimited argument here?

Comment: see the first part of egreg's answer. you defined `\newappend` to take everything up to the next space as `#1` not an argument given by a  `{..}` group,, so in what I suggested in the comment above `\newappend{a}\newappend{b} ` the argument of the first `\newapend` is not `{a}` but `{a}newappend{b}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would it then be better to use syntax like `\def\append{#1}` instead? I.e. surround `#1` with braces (in this case)?

Comment: @FaheemMitha no that's a syntax error. See egreg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle pointed out, using `\edef` with arbitrary material is likely to cause errors. For instance, this will be the case with material containing `\textbf`, and there are plenty of other cases.

## Two ways in LaTeX2e style

I present two techniques in LaTeX2e style that use `\protected@edef` so that macros defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` are not affected. This way, the added material may contain `\textbf`.

These techniques also don't overwrite the `\next` macro, which is always nice (well, they do but automatically restore it when finished). Also note that your `\tmpmacroval` macro wasn't really useful.

Note that your list is duly modified despite the grouping I added, because `\g@addto@macro` uses `\xdef`, which performs a global assignment.

### First technique

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newslist}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newappend}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\next{\endgroup\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{#1,}}%
  \next
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{foo}val}

\begin{document}

\newappend{\foo}
\renewcommand{\foo}{someotherval}
\verb|\newslist| is \newslist.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Explanation**

Let's assume that TeX has just expanded `\newappend{〈argument〉}`. This leaves the following at the front of the input stream:

```latex
\begingroup
\protected@edef\next{\endgroup\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{〈argument〉,}}%
\next
```

Upon execution of `\begingroup`, TeX opens a new group. Then he sees the line:

```latex
\protected@edef\next{\endgroup\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{〈argument〉,}}
```

After `\protected@edef` has been expanded and all the resulting tokens processed, the macro `\next` is defined in the current group. The definition is local to this group, and the previous definition of `\next` (possibly: none) will be automatically restored by TeX as soon as this group ends—that is the main purpose of TeX groups. Now, the next token in the input stream is the `\next` control sequence token. Since it is a macro, TeX expands it, which causes this `\next` token to be replaced by:

```latex
\endgroup\g@addto@macro\newslist{〈expanded argument〉,}
```

(the `\noexpand` tokens have been removed as part of the execution of an `\edef` in the implementation of `\protected@edef`). The next token in the input stream is thus `\endgroup` now. TeX executes it (it is unexpandable, thus it is handled in TeX's stomach, contrary to macros), which closes the current group. As said, this has the effect of cancelling the (re-)definition of `\next` that we did. This is clean. What remains at the front of the input stream is now

```latex
\g@addto@macro\newslist{〈expanded argument〉,}
```

which is exactly what you wanted.

### Second technique

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newslist}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newappend}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{#1,}}%
  \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \next
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{foo}val}

\begin{document}

\newappend{\foo}
\renewcommand{\foo}{someotherval}
\verb|\newslist| is \newslist.

\end{document}
```

Same output as in the previous example.

## Examples with `expl3`

`expl3` has many facilities to deal with list-like material. I'll show some examples with `clist`, i.e. comma-separated lists. This allows easy direct setting from user input, since commas can be entered in the text. For more general lists, you can use `seq` variables. For lists of (key,value) pairs, there is the `prop` module (“property lists”). All these modules are built in the `expl3` language, thus available after `\usepackage{expl3}` or `\usepackage{xparse}`, which loads `expl3.` There is no need to load anything else.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_faheem_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \faheem_append:Nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn #1 {#2} % 'g' for “global”
  }

% Variant that performs one expansion step on the second argument
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \faheem_append:Nn { No }
% Variant that performs \edef-like expansion on the second argument
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \faheem_append:Nn { Nx } % \edef-like expansion 
% There are also 'e' to perform \expanded-like expansion, 'f' for
% \romannumeral-like expansion, etc.

\NewDocumentCommand \newList { m }
  {
    \clist_new:N #1
  }

% In fact, for serious work, better do:
%
% \cs_new_protected:Npn \faheem_new_list:N #1
%   {
%     \clist_new:N #1
%   }
%
% and make \newList call \faheem_new_list:N or \faheem_new_list:c as I do for
% the \append* functions below (the 'c' variant would allow you to choose
% arbitrary names for the clist variable: you would pass whatever name you
% want to the 'c' variant, normally without a leading slash, otherwise that
% would create a strange beast: \\the_passed_name).

\NewDocumentCommand \clearList { O{\g_faheem_clist} }
  {
    \clist_gclear:N #1          % 'g' for “global”
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \appendNoExp { O{\g_faheem_clist} m }
  {
    \faheem_append:Nn #1 {#2}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \appendOneExp { O{\g_faheem_clist} m }
  {
    \faheem_append:No #1 {#2}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \appendFullExp { O{\g_faheem_clist} m }
  {
    \faheem_append:Nx #1 {#2}
  }

% This requires a recent LaTeX release (2020 or later?)
\NewDocumentCommand \appendTextExpand { O{\g_faheem_clist} m }
  {
    % \text_expand:n works inside an 'x'-type argument because it is fully
    % expandable, as indicated by the star in the margin in interface3.pdf.
    \faheem_append:Nx #1 { \text_expand:n {#2} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \useList { O{\g_faheem_clist} m }
  {
    \clist_use:Nn #1 {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\showres}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1.~}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\newList{\somelist}
\appendNoExp{first in default list}
\appendNoExp[\somelist]{first in somelist}

\def\foobar{element with \textbf{non-expandable}\_material}
\def\baz{quux}
\appendOneExp{\foobar}
\appendOneExp[\somelist]{\baz}

\showres{1}
Default list: \useList{, }\par
\verb|\somelist|: \useList[\somelist]{, }

\def\fooleveli{\foolevelii}
\def\foolevelii{\fooleveliii}
\def\fooleveliii{other element}
\appendFullExp{\fooleveli}

\showres{2}
Default list: \useList{, }

\renewcommand{\fooleveliii}{\textbf{non-expandable} \emph{stuff}}
% Expand again \fooleveli, \foolevelii and (the new) \fooleveliii, this time
% with a method that won't break with LaTeX non-expandable commands defined
% with \DeclareRobustCommand.
\appendTextExpand{\fooleveli}

\showres{3}
Default list: \useList{, }.

\def\foobar{overwrite}
\def\fooleveli{overwrite}

\showres{4}
Default list: \useList{, }.\par
\verb|\somelist|: \useList[\somelist]{, }.

\showres{5}
With X as separator: \useList{X}.

\clearList                      % clear the default list

\showres{6}
Y\useList{X}Y

\end{document}
```

[image: expl3]

Note: for expanding text material without causing errors due to non-expandable, non-engine-protected commands like `\textbf`, recent `expl3` has `\text_expand:n`, which is in the spirit of `\protected@edef` (see [Joseph Wright's blog](https://www.texdev.net/2020/01/15/case-changing-in-expl3) and [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)).

Comment: I added an example using `\text_expand:n`.

Comment: Hi @frougon. Trying to understand your examples, but to start with I don't understand your usage of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in the first example. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Hi @FaheemMitha, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @frougon. Thanks for the explanation. So once `\next` is expanded, the definition of `\next` disappears? I see. That's clever. I suppose the idea is that one should avoid "treading" on any pre-existing definition of `\next`?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. To be accurate, the definition is cancelled when the group ends (i.e., when the `\endgroup` from our macro is executed), which is a bit later than “once `\next` is expanded”. But just a tiny bit. Once all tokens from the replacement text of `\newappend` have been digested, you can be sure that `\next` has been restored (possibly as undefined), which is what matters in practice.

Comment: I had forgotten to replace `#1` with 〈argument〉 in the explanation of the first technique. If this was unclear, it should be better now.

Comment: Your second example is basically the same as the first, correct? With the minor difference that `\expandafter` expands `\next` before `\endgroup` is called. And once `\endgroup` is called, the same magic trick happens, and `\next` disappears.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The two techniques are equivalent.

Comment: Hi Frougon. Thank you for the detailed expl3 tutorial. I'm trying to read it, but I'm still not really familiar with `expl3`. Do you recommend `expl3` as a general approach to LaTeX programming over more free-form approaches like the code in my question?

Comment: Hi, `expl3` is great, but I don't think it would be wise to skip the low-level stage with TeX primitives. Indeed, some conditions like “what is allowed in an `x`-type argument” are direct consequences of the way TeX works (what doesn't work inside `\edef` won't work inside an `x`-type argument). But when you have the bases, `expl3` offers very efficient high-level tools. Start with the short [expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) when you feel you are ready, or if you already want to unravel things a bit.

Comment: To be clear: when I wrote “I don't think it would be wise to skip the low-level stage with TeX primitives,” I meant: from a learning perspective. Once the essential aspects of TeX programming are clear for you, you can of course use `expl3` without resorting to low-level TeX stuff. It's just that the `expl3` docs are best understood when you know a bit how TeX works at the token stream level (how macro arguments are gathered, expansion, grouping, what `\protected` is useful for, etc.).

Comment: Hi frougon. I think I understand what you mean. Are you saying that I should stay with the more explicit low level stuff till I have a good understanding of the basic details?

Comment: Could I use `\NewDocumentCommand` with the first two LaTeX 2e versions instead of `\newcommand`, or would it be a poor fit?

Comment: Yes, I think it is important to play for some time with simple macros done with techniques  from the TeXbook chapter 20, and learn what works by expansion and what works by execution. Then all the rest (`expl3`, whatever) should become much easier. As for `\NewDocumentCommand`, you can certainly use it with code like in the first two examples. It is much more powerful than `\newcommand`. There is one big difference: the macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are always `\protected`: they don't expand inside `\edef`, `\write`, `\message`, etc. (expansion-only contexts).  ...

Comment: ... Most of the time, this is desirable. In the somewhat rare occasions where you write a macro that should be able to expand in expansion-only contexts, you can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. But *only use it when you are sure it is appropriate* (i.e., the particular macro has to be “fully expandable”:  it doesn't need execution at all to do its work, all it needs is expansion).

Answer (score 2):

First off: as I've written several times, TeX is ***not*** free-form. There's a huge difference between

```
\def\append#1
{
 \g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}%
}
```

and the code you probably want, namely

```
\def\append#1{%
 \g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}%
}
```

With your code the argument to `\append` is determined as whatever comes after it up to the first space token. So if you write

```
\append{a}Some words
```

the result is that `{a}Some` is appended to the list.

Now to your problem. It's not really clear what kind of input you expect. If the input is *either* text *or* a single macro that expands to text, you can simply do

```
\expandafter\append\expandafter{\foo}
```

If you want instead to pass arbitrary text that may contain macros to be expanded, then you need great care. If this text contains something like `\ref` and the object referenced is still unknown, then you're basically doomed even if you use `\protected@edef`. The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\slist{}
\def\append#1{%
 \protected@xdef\slist{\unexpanded\expandafter{\slist}#1,}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\append{\ref{what}}

\show\slist

\end{document}
```

will print on the terminal

```latex
> \slist=macro:
->\protect \G@refundefinedtrue {\protect \mbox  {\protect \normalfont  \protect
 \bfseries  ??}}\protect \GenericWarning  {               }{LaTeX Warning: Refe
rence `what' on page 1 undefined},.
```

which is probably something you don't really like to see.

Therefore I'll assume the argument to `\append` is either text or a single macro.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\slist{}
\def\append{\@ifstar{\append@expand}{\append@text}}
\def\append@text#1{\g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}}
\def\append@expand#1{\expandafter\append@text\expandafter{#1}}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{something}

\begin{document}

\append{a}\append*{\foo}

\show\slist

\end{document}
```

This will print the expected

```latex
> \slist=macro:
->a,something,.
```

I'd be wary of suggesting the simpler

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\slist{}
\def\append#1{%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\slist\expandafter{#1,}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\foo}{something}

\begin{document}

\append{a}\append*{\foo}

\show\slist

\end{document}
```

that will do the same. You can use this simpler approach if your input is always a string of characters or a single macro expanding to a string of characters (‘string’ in the nontechnical sense, meaning ‘sequence’).

Comment: Hi @egreg. To answer your implied question, the input is basically a label. This is normally just a string of characters, but I've also used a variant which is a single macro which expands to a string, with a string appended. E.g. `\theletternum:2019.09.30`, where `letternum` is a counter, defined by `\stepcounter{letternum}`. And of course this latter variant blows up if it's not expanded first. I don't currently think that the input will get more complicated than that, but of course it's hard to see the future. Which version would you recommend for this use case?

Comment: Can you explain what your `\append` version containing `\protected@xdef\slist{\unexpanded\expandafter{\slist}#1,}%` does? I assume the purpose of this example is to show that bad things can happen if you pass in an arbitrary macro.

Comment: @FaheemMitha If your input is guaranteed to be fully expandable, as in the case you show, you can use `\xdef\slist{\slis}#1,}`

Answer (score 2):

1. With your code a lot of unwanted space tokens come into being:
   Due to `\endlinechar` a return-character (of category code 5(end of line)) is added at the right end of every line. After producing character-tokens like `{1(begin group)` and `}2(end group)` and `112(other)` (as in `#1`=`#6(parameter)112(other)`) the reading apparatus of (La)TeX is in state m (middle of line) and therefore both following category code 5 return characters and following space characters will get tokenized as space tokens. Space tokens in turn yield visible horizontal glue in (restricted) horizontal mode.
2. `\edef` instead of `\protected@edef` might expand things that should not be expanded further.
3. In case the argument of `\newappend` contains hashes (`#`), two consecutive hashes will collapse into a single hash when `\tmpmacroval` is expanded. The same happens when `\next` gets expanded. `\g@addto@macro` in turn doubles hashes. In other words: `\newappend` divides amounts of consecutive hashes by 2.

Rectifying 1 and 2 could turn your code into something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\def\slist{}
\def\newslist{}

\makeatletter
\def\append#1{\g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}}
\def\newappend#1{%%%%
  \def\tmpmacroval{#1}%%%%
  \protected@edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\newslist{\tmpmacroval,}}%
  \next
}%%%
\makeatother

\def\foo{fooval}

\begin{document}
\append{\foo}

\newappend{\foo}

\def\foo{someotherval}

\verb|\slist| is \texttt{\meaning\slist}

\verb|\newslist| is \texttt{\meaning\newslist}

% Here are sequences with four consecutive hashes:    
\def\foo{\def\noexpand\bar####1{Arg of \string\bar\space is ####1}}

\append{\foo}

\newappend{\foo}

\verb|\slist| is \texttt{\meaning\slist}

\verb|\newslist| is \texttt{\meaning\newslist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you look at the last line of the resulting output, you notice that the amount of **four** consecutive hashes `####` in the source gets halved and therefore `\newslist` contains sequences of two hashes only.  (When expanding `\newslist`, amounts of hashes get halved again, thus expandiing `\newslist` yields the tokens:
`fooval,\def\bar#1{Arg of \bar is #1},` ; the second `\bar` is stringified.)

With TeX-engines where both the `\expanded`-primitive and the `\unexpanded`-primitive is available, you can also rectify issue 3 (the collapsing of two consecutive hashes into a single hash during expansion). I'd probably do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyExpandedG@addto@macro[2]{%
  % The following three lines form the \protected@edef-mechanism:
  \let\@@protect\protect
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \afterassignment\restore@protect
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \xdef#1{%
    % \unexpanded inside \edef yields doubling of amounts of hashes.
    \unexpanded\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0%
      % \romannumeral0-\exchange-trickery to get the things that are to be appended
      % expanded fully via \expanded, and to get the macro where things are to be
      % appended expanded once; during expansion - no matter if expansion
      % is only once or fully - amounts of hashes get halved:
      \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\expanded{#2}}%
                                       {\exchange{ }\expandafter#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\newappend[1]{\MyExpandedG@addto@macro\newslist{#1,}}%
\newcommand\append[1]{\g@addto@macro\slist{#1,}}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\slist{}
\newcommand\newslist{}

\newcommand\foo{fooval}

\begin{document}
\append{\foo}

\newappend{\foo}

\def\foo{someotherval}

\verb|\slist| is \texttt{\meaning\slist}

\verb|\newslist| is \texttt{\meaning\newslist}

% Here are sequences with two consecutive hashes:
\def\foo{\def\noexpand\bar##1{Arg of \string\bar\space is ##1}}

\append{\foo}

\newappend{\foo}

\verb|\slist| is \texttt{\meaning\slist}

\verb|\newslist| is \texttt{\meaning\newslist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you look at the last line of the resulting output, you notice that summa summarum the amount of  **two** consecutive hashes `##` in the source does not get halved and therefore `\newslist` contains sequences with the same amount of hashes.